# ERROR ReferenceError: countryCallingCode is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I got error when try to set value for my property `countryCallingCode` which in first option not exist.

```js
this.allData.customerFacingPhone.countryCallingCode = newItem.countryCallingCode
```

I got error:

```
ERROR ReferenceError: countryCallingCode is not defined
```

When try to `console.log(allData);`

I don't have `customerFacingPhone` ... I want to create property of `allData customerFacingPhone` and `.countryCallingCode` and set value...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help in understanding the question

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you haven't declared the type. Try to declare the type like below

```js
export SomeComponent {
  allData: {
    customerFacingPhone: {
      countryCallingCode: any; // <-- elegant would be to define correct type here
    }
  } = Object.create(null);     // <-- initializing empty object

  // some example function
  someFunction() {
    this.allData.customerFacingPhone.countryCallingCode = newItem.countryCallingCode;
  }
}
```

---

More elegant way would be to use a TS Interface to define the type.

**data.ts**

```js
export interface Data {
  customerFacingPhone: Phone;
  someOtherProperty: string;
}

export interface Phone {
  countryCallingCode: string;
  someOtherProperty: number;
}
```

And use it in the controller

```js
import { Data, Phone } from './data';

export SomeComponent {
  allData: Data = Object.create(null);     // <-- initializing empty object

  // some example function
  someFunction() {
    this.allData.customerFacingPhone.countryCallingCode = newItem.countryCallingCode;
  }
}
```